# Navbar won't stay static inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website called facethemusic.co which you are welcome to visit.
It's a music streaming service and social music network so I need a static music player which doesn't automatically refresh everytime a link is clicked. So I use iFrames, however when I scroll the navbar wont stay fixed to the top on the mobile version. And after scrolling 2/3rd of the way down the page on the desktop version the navbar goes away rather than static, does anyone know how to fix this?

P.S. The mobile version "appears" to work when resizing the browser on the desktop but the navbar won't stay static on my iPhone when run there.

Kind regards,

```css
.navbar-custom {
 /* background-color:#297A52; nice green */
    
    background-color:#48D1CC;
    border-radius:0;
    cursor:url(../img/cursor.gif), pointer;
}
  
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:#ffffff;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:transparent;
    cursor:url(../img/cursor.gif), pointer;
}
      
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li a:hover  {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#4DDBB8; /*purple: #660066 */
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.gif), pointer;

}
 
 .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
}     

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
   color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
   background-color:white;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
   background-color:#90C3D4;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
<div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" id="main-navbar" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Face the Revolution!" data-placement="bottom" >FaceTheMusic</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="source.html">Home</a> </li>
               <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li> 
               <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>
                
            </ul>
         <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
 </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
 </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using AJAX for this, iFrames are outdated.

Comment: thanks, but is there anyway to make it work within iframes? For example using javascript/jquery to create a custom static navbar option?

Comment: I've done a bit of research on google and iFrames don't seem to be out of date especially for people like me who don't want to go down the AJAX route and would like to stick to HTML/5 as much as they can.

Comment: Please try and see if the answer below resolve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "overflow-y: scroll;" in the body{-- here --} css of http://facethemusic.co/source.html

```
body{
 ---other existing attributes---
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hopefully it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

It will resolve the issue, you can try this.

Please make this change in CSS file

**Replace this**

```
#mainFrame {
    cursor: url("img/cursor.gif"), pointer;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**with this**

```
#mainFrame {
    cursor: url("img/cursor.gif"), pointer;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It works for the static desktop version, but on the mobile version when I scroll it is still scrolling alongside it.

Comment: could it be to do with this?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: If you change the height of the iframe to 98%, it will fix the issue in mobile devices too. Please try.

Comment: I have tried that too, it still won't work do you have any other fixes to reccomend? Im happy that it is working as is with the static bar on the desktop

Comment: I can debug if you can please let me know, which mobile screen size u r testing coz i have tested on 5.5 inches screen and above.. works well.. lets fix this issue completely together.

Comment: yes I agree let's fix this issue. I'm trying it on an iphone 6 and it will scroll not stay static. have you installed bootstrap? visit facethemusic.co and render that in your phone see if it's static because I'm using your code.

Comment: Its working well on iphone 6 brother, could you please send a screenshot of where 2 scrollbars coming and topnav going inside frame.

I am not able to reproduce this issue. Is this resolved by using 98% height? have you already applied that?

Comment: yes I have applied that it is the code I'm using, is it working with 98% height on your iPhone 6 inside the frame?

Comment: facethemusic.co/source.html works with the static navbar. but when inside the iFrame it won't work on facethemusic.co/index.html on the mobile version

Comment: so do I change the code on the source.html (which is the bit in the iFrame) or the index.html (outside the iFrame) to height:98% which one?

Comment: Sorry for seeing your comments late, I guess you have fixed the issue.. right? Applying the height on iframe.. isn't it?

Comment: yes I have applied the height on the iFrame and on the index.html file just to make sure, but it still won't work 
however should I,
modify the css further including the body,html {height:100% } tag?

Comment: Please find the fix in the below answer.